# How do I delete a folder using the Amazon s3 management console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I try to delete a folder from a bucket using the Amazon Web Service s3 Management Console...

I get a confirmation message which I answer OK.
An item is added to the right hand pane saying the delete has started

BUT the delete never finishes and the folder never goes away.

Versioning is turned off on the bucket containing the folder.

The folder is empty.  I also tried putting something in the folder but that didn't help.

Comment: That should just work. You are doing it correctly. Perhaps try reloading the page in the browser to confirm that it really isn't getting deleted. I've seen issues where things like this don't always refresh properly in the AWS web console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't delete directory from Amazon S3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668017/cant-delete-directory-from-amazon-s3)

Comment: *"Versioning is turned off"*  Do you mean versioning is not enabled because it has never been enabled, or versioning is suspended but was previously enabled?  Potentially very different implications.  Also, the bucket logs may give you some idea of what the console is actually trying to do.  If you don't have that enabled, you will likely wish sooner or later that you did, so now is probablg a good time to turn it on.

Comment: Versioning was NEVER turned on.

Comment: I turned on logging on the bucket containing the folder in question and then deleted the folder WITHOUT any problems!  Nothing was logged for the delete.

Comment: Use AWS-CLI, its very easy to install & powerful than web UI. I got the same problem but when I used AWS Cli it completed very fast.